# CodeForce-A. Way Too Long Words Wrong answer on test 1 but code working on my pc

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't figure it out,

why code force says error

while on my PC working perfectly

Please help me to solve this problem.

I have added here the full code-snippet.

I have updated to code force for submission.

```js
function main() {
var n = readline();
if (n.length < 11) {
  console.log(n);
} else {
  let x = `${n.slice(0, 1)}${n.length - 2}${n.slice(n.length - 1)}`;
  console.log(x);
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

readline() function will not defined.
Because of you don't declare method that method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).